# Is <div style="width: ;height: ;background: "> CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is `<div style="width: ;height: ;background: ">` CSS?

Comment: If you don't give values to styles, it won't have any effect on the element, but it is still CSS.

Comment: The above code is HTML code, **not** CSS code. It ***contains*** some so-called inline style rules which in this case are syntactically incorrect since they are missing values. Those rules are based on CSS.

Answer (score 10):

For example :

```html
<div style="height:100px; width:100px; background:#000000"></div>
```

here.

you give css to div of **height** and **width** having **100px** and **background** as **black**.

**PS :** try to avoid **inline-css** you can make external CSS and import in your html file.

you can refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) for CSS

hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is called **Inline CSS**, Here you styling the `div` using some height, width, and background.

Here the example:

```
<div style="width:50px;height:50px;background color:red">
```

You can achieve same using **Internal** or **External CSS**

2.Internal CSS:

```
  <head>
    <style>
    div {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
    foreground-color:white;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
```

3.External CSS:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
```

style.css /*external css file*/

```
 div {
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        background-color:red;
    }
```

Comment: No, it's HTML ***containing*** inline css.

Comment: anything inside the `<style>` tag is CSS not HTML

Comment: There is no `<style>` ***tag*** in OP's question. It's a `<div>` tag hosting a `style` **attribute** . You need to get the terms clear.

Answer (score 0):

1)Yes it is, when there is style then it is styling your code(css).2) is belong to html it is like a container that keep your css.

Comment: It's HTML, not CSS.